# Duplicate results obtained for awk command to replace field value

Tags: awk

I have file that contain records of animals and birds in our shop, a small snippet of which is given below:

Dogs: 4
Cats: 10
Parrots: 5

I want a one liner with awk if possible to increase number of cats by 1 and decrease number of cubs by 3. The command should be one liner and not using pipes. Because with pipes i have obtained desired results but i need to complete this in single awk command.

Output required is:
Dogs: 4
Cats: 11
Parrots: 2
I was using below command to do this:

Try 1:

```
awk -F ':' '{OFS=":"}; NR==2{$2=$2+1}1; NR==3{$2=$2-3}1' file
```

Try 2

```
awk -F ':' '{OFS=":"}; /Cats/ {$2=$2+1}1; /Parrots/ {$2=$2-3}1' file
```

Output of both commands is:

```
Dogs: 4
Dogs: 4
Cats: 11
Cats: 11
Parrots: 5
Parrots: 2
```

Results were duplicating. I would have done uniq to filter duplicates but the problem is the third row of Cubs is showing original as well as changed value. While second row is showing two times changed value.

Also i wanted to know that as sed has ability to do multiple changes in one single command using -e option or ; like sed -e '1d' -e '$d' file or sed '1d;$d' file, do awk has such capability. Because i tried same thing but i got duplicated results.

Please changes and clarification on my command are invited.

Comment: Asking for a `one liner` tells us you only care about brevity instead of all the things that actually matter in software (clarity, robustness, efficiency, portability, etc.) and so greatly reduces the number of people who'll be willing to help you. You'd be better off not asking for that and then accepting the briefest solution you get that's also clear, robust, efficient, portable, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F ':' 'BEGIN {OFS=":"} /Cats/ {$2=$2+1} /Parrots/ {$2=$2-3} 1' file
```

The above increases Cats by 1 and decreases Parrots by 3.

Your command prints twice because the pattern `1` with empty action appears twice in your command.

I've moved setting of `OFS` to a `BEGIN` block, so that it does not do that for every line. I've included the pattern `1` only once at the end so that the default `print($0)` action runs only once, after all modifications are done.

Answer (score 0):

It is printing twice because you are asking it to print twice. The meaning of `1;` is "this is a true condition which will match on every line; do the default action at this point (that is, print the current input record)". If you only want that to happen once, only do it once (probably at the very end of the script).

As you have actually already discovered, the processng model of Awk is quite similar to that of `sed`; the entire script is applied to each input line (or, in Awk, more generally, each record, where by default a record is a line, but you can easily change that) in turn, and whatever changes you make to the input record during the script's execution will be visible in subsequent lines of the script. However, as Awk is much more general than `sed`, many possible script actions do not directly affect the current input line; you could manipulate variables, call functions, and generally do anything a proper grown-up programming language can do (but be nice to `sed` even though it's so little; it does the one thing it does really well, albeit obscurely).